# Creating abstract ViewModels wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, viewmodel, relaycommand

I'm trying to create an abstract ViewModel class, and several ViewModel classes which will inherit the abstract ViewModel and implement it.

So far I'm using `RelayCommand` and it doesn't compile.

Can such a thing be done?

I'm adding my code:

**RelayCommand class:**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> m_executeAction;
    private readonly Predicate<object> m_canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeAction) : this(executeAction, null) { }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> executeAction, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (executeAction == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeAction");

        m_executeAction = executeAction;
        m_canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object canExecuteParameter)
    {
        return (m_canExecute == null || m_canExecute(canExecuteParameter));
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object canExecuteParameter)
    {
        m_executeAction(canExecuteParameter);
    }
}
```

**The ViewModelsBase class:**

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null) return;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnDispose() {}

    public void Dispose()
    {
        OnDispose();
    }
}
```

**The MainViewModel class:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IViewModel m_testViewModel;
    private bool m_isFirstPlugin = true;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        TestViewModel = new FirstViewModel();
    }

    public IViewModel TestViewModel
    {
        get { return m_testViewModel; }
        set
        {
            m_testViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NewViewModel");
        }
    }

    private ICommand m_changeCommand;

    public ICommand ChangeCommand
    {
        get { return m_changeCommand ?? (m_changeCommand = new RelayCommand(Change)); }
        set { m_changeCommand = value; }
    }

    private void Change(object parameter)
    {
        TestViewModel.Dispose();
        TestViewModel = null;

        if (m_isFirstPlugin)
            TestViewModel = new SecondViewModel();
        else
            TestViewModel = new FirstViewModel();

        m_isFirstPlugin = !m_isFirstPlugin;
    }
}
```

**IViewModel class:**

```
public class IViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ICommand m_testCommand;

    public ICommand TestCommand
    {
        get { return m_testCommand ?? (m_testCommand = new RelayCommand(Test)); }
        set { m_testCommand = value; }
    }

    protected virtual void Test(object parameter) { }
}
```

**FirstViewModel class:**

```
public class FirstViewModel : IViewModel
{
    protected override void Test(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("On First Plugin.");
    }
}
```

**SecondViewModel class:**

```
public class SecondViewModel : IViewModel
{
    protected override void Test(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("On Second Plugin.");
    }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmInheritence.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="Testing" Height="100" Width="180"
    xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MvvmInheritence" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="Transparent">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <Local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="Test!" Foreground="DarkRed" Background="LightBlue"  Height="25" Width="100" Command="{Binding TestCommand, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding TestViewModel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button x:Name="ChangeButton" Content="Change Plugin" Foreground="DarkRed" Background="LightBlue"  Height="25" Width="100" Command="{Binding ChangeCommand, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This code does compile (I made changes to make it work) but for some reason, I'm always getting "On First Plugin" even though the `Change` function is called, and the `ViewModel` is correctly changed.

What am I missing?

Comment: What error do you have? Also can you add code of your base ViewModel class and RelayCommand class?

Comment: I do it all the time.  Are you using an MVVM library, or just rolling your own implementation for your project?  Also, posting the smallest sample of what doesn't compile goes a long way to let us help you.  It's quite possible you are implementing an interface and are missing the abstract declaration for that method/property.

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found the glitch.

Int the `MainViewModel` class, the `TestViewModel` property should be changed from:

```
public IViewModel TestViewModel
{
    get { return m_testViewModel; }
    set
    {
        m_testViewModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("NewViewModel");
    }
}
```

To:

```
public IViewModel TestViewModel
{
    get { return m_testViewModel; }
    set
    {
        m_testViewModel = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TestViewModel");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom MVVM starts with creating an abstract ViewModelBase class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

However, based on your `RelayCommand` comment I assume you are using the MVVM Light framework? Then instead of implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` your abstract ViewModel should inherit from MVVM Lights `ViewModelBase` class.

RelayCommands will be properties of your ViewModelBase not the base class you inherit from.

Comment: Updated my question.